# How do I create a foreign key to the User table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a new model called Tickets which I want to ensure always has a valid userID assigned to it.

I'm using `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` to setup the profile which also gives the error **NameError: name 'User' is not defined** when I try to run syndb.

How do I setup a foreign key to make sure this always is the case?

```
## tickets/models.py

class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,)
    # More model stuff.



# accounts/models.py   

class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

Comment: You've done it - what doesn't work for you?

Comment: I can't access the user class it seems. I assume that is created automatically with the django.contrib.auth app since I can login to the django admin and whatnot.

Answer (score 26):

so the problem was I was missing an import on my models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Answer (score 10):

For future reference, according to the [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model), it is recommended to reference the User model like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```