# Django: Foreign Key relation with User Table does not validate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Consider the following django model

```
from django.db import models                                                                                                                             
from django.contrib import auth
class Topic(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey('auth.models.User')                                                                                                          
   name = models.CharField(max_length = NameMaxLength , unique = True)
   version_number = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add  = True)
   modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
   update_frequency = models.IntegerField()
```

This model does not validate even after installing the `auth_user` table.

```
In [3]: auth.models.User.objects.all()
Out[3]: [<User: admin>]
```

The above statement is from django-admin shell

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Error: One or more models did not validate:
topic: 'user' has a relation with model auth.models.User, which has either not
been installed or is abstract.
```

I am using django v1.0.4 with pinax 0.7.2 on ubuntu 11.04 , with sqlite3 database

The following Questions did not help much:

- [Foreign key to User table in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183757/foreign-key-to-user-table-in-django)
- [How do I create a foreign key to the User table in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244573/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-to-the-user-table-in-django)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
from django.db import models                                                                                                                             
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

`'auth.User'` would have worked, too.  It's not Python's library syntax, it's the Django ORM's "app.model" syntax.  But you should only pass the model as a string if you're desperately trying to solve a circular dependency.  And if you have a circular dependency, your code is eff'd.

Comment: Thanks That validated the model and installed it .

Answer (score 7):

Even I faced same issue,

The error message is clear: you haven't installed the User model.

```
Add "django.contrib.auth" to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py.
```

That all..Hope it will solve this issue, worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but in different situation.
I splitted the models.py in two files:

```
myapp/
    models/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
```

In foo.py I had two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    attr1 = ... etc

class FooBar(models.Model):
    other = ... etc
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'foo'
```

I solved adding Meta also in Foo model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    attr1 = ... etc

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'foo'
```